# Why do python instances have no __name__ attribute?

Tags: python

```
>>> class Foo:
...   'it is a example'
...   print 'i am here'
... 
i am here
>>> Foo.__name__
'Foo'
>>> Foo().__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute '__name__'
>>> Foo.__doc__
'it is a example'
>>> Foo().__doc__
'it is a example'
>>> Foo.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': 'it is a example'}
>>> Foo().__dict__
{}
>>> Foo.__module__
'__main__'
>>> Foo().__module__
'__main__'
>>> myname=Foo()
>>> myname.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute `__name__`
```

What is the reason instances have  no attribute  `__name__`?
maybe it is ok that the `__name__` of instance-myname is  `myname`.
would you mind  tell me more logical, not the unreasonable grammar rules?

Comment: What makes you think there is supposed to be a `__name__` attribute on instances? The [relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) says it exists for classes (and other things), but I don't see any mention of it for instances.

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__name__#class.__name__): `__name__` is the name of a "class or type", not an instance of a class or type. Why should instances have `__name__`s?

Comment: Did you mean `Foo().__class__.__name__` ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're seeing an artifact of the implementation of classes and instances.  The `__name__` attribute isn't stored in the class dictionary; therefore, it can't be seen from a direct instance lookup.

Look at `vars(Foo)` to see that only `__module__` and `__doc__` are in the class dictionary and are visible to the instance.

For the instance to access the name of a class, it has to work its way upward with `Foo().__class__.__name__`. Also note that classes have other attributes such as `__bases__` that aren't in the class dictionary and likewise cannot be directly accessed from the instance.

Comment: I understand that is is dynamically set on the class during runtime. However, my IDE (PyCharm) is complaining about this error. Is there any way to avoid this without disabling Type checking?